# Posting foreign key IDs in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working on a Django API using Django Rest Framework. I have two related entities, `Event` and `Venue`. An Event takes place in a Venue.

By using nested serialization I'm able to return the following to my API users:

```
{
  "id": "1234",
  "name": "My event",
  "venue": {
    "id": "5678",
    "name": "My venue"
  }
}
```

This is all as expected. However, I'm now trying to POST an event and reference the venue as a parameter:

```
POST /api/events/

{
  "name": "My new event",
  "venue_id": "5678"
}
```

But I'm struggling to make this work. I'm trying both `venue_id` and `venue` as attribute names (I'd prefer `_id` as it would be more correct, but it wouldn't be a big deal).

I'm using the following serializers:

```python
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'created_at', 'updated_at']

class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = VenueSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'venue', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

What would be the correct approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using PrimaryKey(the venue_id) instead of the whole model object, you may use [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield) instead of a nested serializer.

In your example, it would look like:

```
class EventCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Venue.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'venue', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

And you shall use the request:

```
{
  "name": "My new event",
  "venue": "5678"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @philoj. I understand that I would need to create separate serializers and separate views, to differentiate between the creation and the retrieval operations, is this correct?

Comment: Yes. It is even better if you create a single Viewset(https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/) instead of two Views and override get_serializer() method to return the appropriate serializer during 'create' and 'list' actions. You may check against the value of self.action to distinguish this.